# GWT DecoratorPanel problem in Firefox 3.5

Tags: gwt, firefox3.5

Rounded corners ing GWT's DecoratorPanels don't look right for me in FF3.5. See the gap below the upper right-hand corner:

http://img.skitch.com/20090705-c95g8b1cn33t22wnypk4h5mjwt.jpg

Anyone else having this problem? The showcase app uses rounded corners without issue. What am I doing wrong?

I'm on GWT 1.6.4.

-Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, just figured it out... very frustrated with myself for not
thinking of this sooner (I won't say how many hours I burned up).

I did a fresh install of 3.5 on another user account and it did not
have the same problem. It ends up that somehow my zoom in FF got set
to -1 causing weirdness on decorated corners.

UPDATE: I Checked FF3.0. The gaps only appear in FF3.5 so is this a FF3.5 bug or something GWT should program around? Maybe GWT trunk addresses this?

-Mike

Comment: If you search bugzilla, this is quite common. The root source is a integer rounding off error. This is not FF3.5 specific -- it appear in some rare case in 3.0 as well.